# Regular Expression for a condition

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am building a HTML template system, I need to allow the users to add condition as shown below.

example of the if condition;

```
..HTML...
[if:UserLevel > 100]
    ...conditional HTML...
[endif]
...More HTML....
```

I am in need of a **PHP** Regular Expression that matches;

```
[if:$]
   $
[endif]
```

where $ if variable/wildcard.

Answer (score 3):

```
"/\[if:([^]]+)](.*?)\[endif]/s"
```

Will do what you asked for.

**Note** that just using plain regex like this for your templating is not an effective approach, and will not even work in some cases. For example you cannot nest these if statements when parsting them with such a regex.

There are many templating languages out there, I suggest you have a look at some of them. (Unless you are only doing this for educational purposes.)

Comment: How to I extract the condition or the body of the match?

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match("(\[if:([^]+])\](.*?)\[endif\])is",$data);
```

The `s` modifier allows for there to be newlines in your input data.

If you capture the match, `$match[1]` will be the condition, and `$match[2]` the HTML inside it.

Comment: Fantastic, ill try it out asap.

Comment: I tried this, it executed without errors but returned an empty array. I might be doing smething wrong, Im using pre_match_all.